# Ruby Geocoder [Rails] - How to Traverse this Result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed [Ruby Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com) and I am trying to traverse the `Geocoder::Result`, but keep coming up short.  I am in rails console, and have used the following:

`s = Geocoder.search("90210")`

Which returns the following:

`[#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x007ff295579ad8 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"90210", "short_name"=>"90210", "types"=>["postal_code"]}, {"long_name"=>"Beverly Hills", "short_name"=>"Beverly Hills", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Los Angeles", "short_name"=>"Los Angeles", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"California", "short_name"=>"CA", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address"=>"Beverly Hills, CA 90210, USA", "geometry"=>{"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>34.1354771, "lng"=>-118.3867129}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>34.065094, "lng"=>-118.4423781}}, "location"=>{"lat"=>34.1030032, "lng"=>-118.4104684}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>34.1354771, "lng"=>-118.3867129}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>34.065094, "lng"=>-118.4423781}}}, "types"=>["postal_code"]}, @cache_hit=nil>]`

How can I access a specific part of the Result?  I have tried the following:

`s.result.city`, `result.city`, `s.data`?? But none of these work.  Any ideas would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  The docs say "Geocoder.search returns an array of Geocoder::Result objects"

Hence, I needed this:

`s[0].city` <= Beverly Hills  OR
`s.first.city` (thanks to @fotanus)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://geocoder.rubyforge.org/), it is a struct, so you should access the values as an indexed symbol, like the following:

```
result[:city]
```

The link has what can be accessed from this object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried `result[:city]` and `s.result[:city]` and both give me the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method "result" for #<Array:0x007f8033907648>`

Comment: @Dodinas you need to call `s.first[:city]`, since `s` seems to be a list (it starts with `[` in your output) - of course, since it is a list, can have more than one result, so you might want to call `s.each do |result| ` to handle each one.

Answer (score 0):

When using "Geocoder.search", you need to parse through several layers to get to the city.  The following will return "Beverly Hills".

```
s.first.data["address_components"][1]["short_name"]
```

If you want to use the syntax as seen in other answers, you need to create a new instance of geocoder instead of using Geocoder.search