# Get object properties Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I am trying to get city using postcode with `geocoder` gem and I works as I get such object:

```
---
      - !ruby/object:Geocoder::Result::Google
        data:
          address_components:
          - long_name: AB10 1AA
            short_name: AB10 1AA
            types:
            - postal_code
          - long_name: Aberdeen
            short_name: Aberdeen
            types:
            - locality
            - political
          - long_name: Aberdeen City
            short_name: Aberdeen City
            types:
            - administrative_area_level_2
            - political
          - long_name: United Kingdom
            short_name: GB
            types:
            - country
            - political
          - long_name: Aberdeen
            short_name: Aberdeen
            types:
            - postal_town
          formatted_address: Aberdeen, Aberdeen City AB10 1AA, UK
          geometry:
            bounds:
              northeast:
                lat: 57.1487081
                lng: -2.0960462
              southwest:
                lat: 57.1478514
                lng: -2.0972085
            location:
              lat: 57.1482317
              lng: -2.0966478
            location_type: APPROXIMATE
            viewport:
              northeast:
                lat: 57.1496287302915
                lng: -2.095278369708498
              southwest:
                lat: 57.1469307697085
                lng: -2.097976330291502
          types:
          - postal_code
        cache_hit:
```

Now I have problem with getting city... As I understand it is object so (lets call it location) location.data.address_components.long_name but I get error like `undefined method`data' for #`... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ouhh... This post [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668977/ruby-geocoder-rails-how-to-traverse-this-result?rq=1) helped me! Solution is simple as that: `location[0].city`